# Did the Joker ever refer to himself as the Joker?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight, the-joker

In *The Dark Knight*, Heath Ledger played the Joker.  But did his character ever explicitly refer to himself by that name, aside from the "calling cards" mentioned at the end of *Batman Begins*?

Comment: Aah, that's interesting...

Comment: Joker calls himself "The Agent of Chaos", but i can't recall him saying "Joker". Using Clown masks, and Joker getup is a different thing.

Comment: I've just had a scan through the screenplay book and I can't find any instance of the Joker calling himself "the Joker" in the Dark Knight script.

Comment: Does he use the name in one of those videos?

Comment: Actually, [everyone else](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_(film)) [called him, the joker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/quotes?item=qt1148950)!

Comment: He says it in '[Injustice: Gods Among Us '](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000180/quotes) - "*Harley, it's me. I'm The Joker. Look. it says so right here on my underwear.*"

Answer (score 11):

### No

A search of the transcript of *The Dark Knight* reveals 37 mentions of the word "Joker," but all of them are spoken by people other than the Joker himself.

The script indicates that *others*  "call him the Joker," not that it is a name he chose for himself:

> DOPEY: I know why they call him the Joker.
>
> HAPPY: So why do they call him the Joker?
>
> DOPEY: I heard he wears makeup.
>
> HAPPY: Makeup?
>
> DOPEY: Yeah! to scare people. You know, war paint?

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-N7V8dzMGtUE/TpPQ8Owu_EI/AAAAAAAAA1w/Sfg4rOBdkOw/s400/Joker+-+Batman+686.jpg

Comment: Nope. It's Neil Gaiman's take on the Joker from ['Batman: Whatever Happened to the Caped Crusader?'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Whatever_Happened_to_the_Caped_Crusader%3F).

Comment: Just checking, it's not the Joker wearing the "dopey" mask is it?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the closest he gets is referring to jokers (playing cards) as "my card."

Comment: Was this before or after he received the moniker?